# Date Format Problem

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How to get this format of date from NSString;

`Wed, 22 Jun 2011 12:36:00 +0100` to `Wed, 22 Jun 2011.`

Thanks

Comment: could you edit your question to clarify what you are trying to achieve? Are you formatting an NSDate object as an NSString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code.

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Wed, 22 Jun 2011 12:36:00 +0100";

    // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];  

    // Convert date object to desired output format
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM d YYYY"];
    dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Date -- %@",dateStr);
    [dateFormat release];
```

Answer (score 1):

The minimalistic version is `E, d MMM y` or to specify 2 digit days and 4 digit years `E, dd MMM yyyy`. The Date Formatter uses the [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).