# Having trouble getting the date from a JSON call

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

I am pulling a date from JSON in the format of "1900-01-01T00:00:00-06:00"

The code I am currently trying (and failing to parse with) is this

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"];
tempDate = [formatter dateFromString:trimmedString];
```

I then want to display what I pull in the MM-dd-yyyy format after I actually get the date back in the correct format.

I am not sure of how many SSS and ZZ's I need at the end, and have tried multiple combinations to no avail. Any Suggestions?

Comment: "S" are sub seconds and you don't have them in your format so I don't think you need "S" at all.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435954/parse-json-date-into-nsdate-depending-user-settings

Comment: Your format does not match your data.  See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns.  (In particular, you want to end your format with "ZZZZZ".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need five "Z"s

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
```